# Weird SQL Error (Bug)

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

So this is really weird.

I run a sql command from .net on sqlserver with a 'Select Count(*)' and get a response like "Needs attention CA" (which is in a varchar of one field of one record of the inner joined tables).

Huh? How can Count(*) return a string? 999 out of 1000 times this code executes correctly. Just sometimes on some clients servers it will throw a string of errors for an hour or so only to miraculously stop again.

This is my sqlcommand:

```
SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   patientsappointments 
       INNER JOIN appointmenttypes 
               ON patientsappointments.appointmenttypeid = 
                  appointmenttypes.appointmenttypeid 
WHERE  ( ( patientsappointments.date > @WeekStartDate 
           AND patientsappointments.date < @WeekFinishDate ) 
         AND ( patientsappointments.status = 'Pending' ) 
         AND ( patientsappointments.doctorid = @DoctorID ) 
         AND ( appointmenttypes.appointmentname <> 'Note' ) )
```

And these are the parameters:

```
@WeekStartDate       = 24/06/2013 12:00:00 AM (DateTime)
@WeekFinishDate      = 1/07/2013 12:00:00 AM (DateTime)
@DoctorID            = 53630c67-3a5a-406f-901c-dbf6b6d1b20f (UniqueIdentifier)
```

I do a sqlcmd.executescalar to get the result. Any ideas?

The actual executed code is:

```
    SyncLock lockRefresh
        Dim WeekFulfilled, WeekPending As Integer
                Using conSLDB As New SqlConnection(modLocalSettings.conSLDBConnectionString)
                    Dim mySQL As SqlCommand
                    mySQL = New SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PatientsAppointments INNER JOIN AppointmentTypes ON PatientsAppointments.AppointmentTypeID = AppointmentTypes.AppointmentTypeID " & _
                                                "WHERE ((PatientsAppointments.Date > @WeekStartDate AND PatientsAppointments.Date < @WeekFinishDate) AND (PatientsAppointments.Status = 'Pending') " & _
                                                "AND (PatientsAppointments.DoctorID = @DoctorID) AND (AppointmentTypes.AppointmentName <> 'Note'))", conSLDB)
                    Try
                        mySQL.Parameters.Add("@WeekStartDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.AddDays(-MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.DayOfWeek).AddDays(1)
                        mySQL.Parameters.Add("@WeekFinishDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.AddDays(-MonthCalendar1.SelectionStart.Date.DayOfWeek).AddDays(8)
                        mySQL.Parameters.Add("@DoctorID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = cboDoctors.SelectedValue
                        conSLDB.Open()
                        'got errors here like "Conversion from string "R2/3" to type 'Integer' is not valid." Weird.
                        'failing on deadlock - maybe due to simultaneous updating from udp event. Try adding random delay to refresh
                        WeekPending = mySQL.ExecuteScalar
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        ErrorSender.SendError("frmAppointmentBook - RefreshHeader 1", ex, New String() {String.Format("mySQL.commandtext: {0}", mySQL.CommandText), _
                                                                                                        String.Format("mySQL.Parameters: {0}", clsErrorSender.ParamsListToString(mySQL.Parameters))})
                    End Try
                    Me.lblPendingWeek.Text = WeekPending
                    Try
                        mySQL.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PatientsAppointments INNER JOIN AppointmentTypes ON PatientsAppointments.AppointmentTypeID = AppointmentTypes.AppointmentTypeID WHERE " & _
                                                   "(PatientsAppointments.Date > @WeekStartDate AND PatientsAppointments.Date < @WeekFinishDate) AND (PatientsAppointments.Status = 'Fulfilled') AND " & _
                                                   "(PatientsAppointments.DoctorID = @DoctorID) AND (AppointmentTypes.AppointmentName <> 'Note')"
                        'didn't get the error here... but just in case...
                        WeekFulfilled = mySQL.ExecuteScalar
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        ErrorSender.SendError("frmAppointmentBook - RefreshHeader 2", ex, New String() {String.Format("mySQL.commandtext: {0}", mySQL.CommandText)})
                    End Try
                    conSLDB.Close()
                End Using
End SyncLock
```

The exact error message is:

```
System.InvalidCastException
Conversion from string "Needs Attention DC" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

Comment: Either the .NET application is executing a different piece of `SQL` than expected.  Or in your procedure/function another `SELECT` statement is executed after the `COUNT`.  Run the statement in management studio, what do you get?

Comment: What is the **exact** error message? `"Needs attention CA"` is not a SQL Server error message.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I don't think there is an error message.  SQL is returning different output than expected.

Comment: Oh I see. Well `COUNT(*)` can't possibly return that as data. So either the query is different or they have a bug in the code consuming the result.

Comment: @MartinSmith - yeah exactly. I assume the command getting executed is not what the OP thinks.

Comment: This code executes at least hundreds of times per day in dozens of clients offices. The error will only show every few days - typically 10 or 20 times in an hour and then stops. It occurs in just some offices not all. I am aware of the documentation - that's what makes it weird. I've added the exact code that executes to the question. @DarrenDavies the error never shows in SSMS.

Comment: @MartinSmith The error occurs because I try to put the result of the execute scalar into an integer and a string can't fit.

Comment: @RichieRich - [`SELECT COUNT(*) isn't broken`](http://pragmatictips.com/26) so you'll probably need to show more code.

Comment: @MartinSmith Just added. I'm guessing it's ado.net, not `select count(*)` in error.

Comment: Does `conSLDB` have any events attached? Are you doing anything on `StateChange`?

Comment: No events. I thought down that path too. This code refreshes quite often in a busy office so I added a `synclock` block around it and the `conSLDB` is instantiated with a `Using` block which starts just before the `SqlCommand` is instantiated and closes just after it is used. There are no events attached to it.

Comment: I can't see anyway this can happen with the code you posted. Are the problem clients definitely on the same code version? You say this  throw a string of errors for an hour or so. Have you been able to do any tracing to see what queries are actually being executed?

Comment: I've had this error for a couple of years and every couple of months hit my head against it again. Gone through probably 100 versions of code base. The client doesn't see it so it's not urgent, only very puzzling. I have returned progressively more and more data in the error message and re-written the code several times adding parameters, synclocks, using blocks etc. Still the same. In the error message I return the exact sql and params executed.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with the `COUNT(*)` portion of  your code.  The problem is somewhere else in your query.  What that particular error is telling you is that at some point you are comparing a character field (it probably usually contains numbers) to an integer field.  One of the values of the character field happens to be "`Needs Attention DC`".  If I had to guess it is probably either `patientsappointments.appointmenttypeid` or `appointmenttypes.appointmenttypeid`.  Double check the datatype of each of those columns to make sure they are in fact `INT`.  If they are both `INT` then start checking the other explicitly named columns in your query to see if you have any surprises.

Comment: No this isn't the case. The error is a `.NET` error (`System.InvalidCastException`) not a SQL Server error (which would be `Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'xyz' to data type int.` and raised as a `SqlException`

Comment: Sometimes the result will be another string from the same field in the joined table: `AppointmentTypes.AppointmentName`. You'll note that field does appear in the `WHERE` clause. It seems pretty random. The `ID` fields are all sql uniqueidentifiers, not int.

Comment: The values of the parameters are definitely as noted as the error sender gets them from the SqlCommand (and 999 out of 1000 times it works perfectly as expected).

Answer (score 1):

You must have an error somewhere in your implementation...

[Per the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx), count always returns an **int** data type value.

Comment: You'd think! I added the exact code that fails (occasionally and only in production and then only sometimes). The error is caught in that very try-catch so there is no other command or stored procedure involved.

Comment: Are you reusing the mySQL var to run other queries? what's the type of WeekPending var?

Comment: Also, please check the datatype of these columns (patientsappointments.appointmenttypeid, appointmenttypes.appointmenttypeid)

Comment: MySQL is defined as a SqlCommand  just before the try-catch. It is re-used immediately after this code in a similar query for a month instead of week. But that's after.

Comment: patientsappointments.appointmenttypeid and appointmenttypes.appointmenttypeid are both sql uniqueidentifier

Comment: Count(*) can't return a varchar. If it's failing intermitently, it's likely that the SQL Server is assuming the column that has the value 'Needs Attention DC' is an INT column, but during the execution finds out that it has VARCHAR values, and so it generates the exception you're seeing...

Comment: Does running this select without the where work? `SELECT Count(*) 
FROM   patientsappointments 
       INNER JOIN appointmenttypes 
               ON patientsappointments.appointmenttypeid = 
                  appointmenttypes.appointmenttypeid`

Comment: That executes perfectly. But so does the original query 999 out of 1000 times. I have run dbcc checktable on the two tables in more than one db with nothing found

Comment: This part `Dim WeekPending As Int32 = mySQL.ExecuteScalar` doesn't even compile. I'm sure the error must be in the code that you didn't post... :)

Comment: I extended the code block to show the creation of `WeekPending`, the `Using` block for the `SqlCommand` and the `SyncLock`. btw, `Dim WeekPending As Int32 = mySQL.ExecuteScalar` compiles just fine. True there is an implicit type conversion.

Comment: Hum, can't really see anything wrong with the code. (1) To test for corruption try running DBCC CHECKDB on the database.  (2) To fix execution bugs on the SQL Server, try installing the latest SQL Server Service Pack...

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make another guess. I am guessing that this is a multi threading issue. You probably are sharing the connection between multiple threads. Once in a while the thread will get that man from somewhere else and execute it. Make sure that the connection variable is local, and only one thread can access it at a time.

*As Martin points out, the following answer is wrong. I'm keeping this here to show that this is wrong.*

From what everyone has already said, there is a type mismatch on your columns. Since your where clause appears to be fine, and your join is fine, it must be elsewhere. I would check to see if patientsappointments or appointmenttypes are views. Maybe the view has a join that's throwing the exception. Check the schema definition of all your joins/where's. Somewhere in there you're storing integers in a character field. It's fine for most rows, but one of them has your string.

If it's not in your views, it may be a trigger somewhere. The point is that somewhere there is a schema mismatch. Once you find your schema mismatch, you can find the row by querying for that string.

Comment: This would raise a `SqlException` not a `System.InvalidCastException`. And there is no such thing as `SELECT` triggers.

Comment: In case it helps, the tables are just tables; no views.

Comment: @RichieRich I am guessing that your connection is shared either accidentally or purposefully. Please make sure that each execution gets its own connection.

Comment: @jtseng threading is still my best guess too. I have extended the code block above to show how I use the connection in a `Using` block and have a `SyncLock` to block re-entry.

Comment: @RichieRich You're declaring these things as local variables, so I don't see how you can share them. Now I'm just grasping at straws that I don't understand, but maybe it's something to do with the connection string. Best of luck fixing this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Since this doesn't always happen, it must be a result of one of the paramenter values that is sent in. This is one of the lbuiggest problems with using dynamic SQL. What I would do is create the dymanic SQl and then store it in a database logging table with the date and time and user who executed it. Then when you get the exception, you can find the exact SQL code that was sent.  Most likely you need more controls on the input variables to ensure the data placed in them is of the correct data type.

Comment: I do exactly that. In fact, in the catch block I send an email every time the error occurs with the command text and parameters. The sql command and parameters shown in the question are cut and pasted straight from the error email. Still, dodgy parameters would lead to a sql error not return a string that can't be put in an integer.